# How to detect the unload event of an iFrame

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, single-page-application

I'd need your help because I have a modal in react SPA which contains an iFrame (*fullscreen* is allowed) and, when I click on fullscreen and then close (with *x* button) the modal, it causes a redirect on the parent page. I tried to add a listener on che "unload" event but nothing change.

Do you have any idea what causes this behaviour?

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };

    this.mediaRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mediaRef.current.addEventListener('unload', this.onCloseEvent);
  }

  onCloseEvent = (event) => {
     // it should cause the closing of the modal
     this.props.setSelectedMedia(null);
  }

  renderMedia = () => {
    if (this.props.selectedMedia.type.includes("image")) {
      return (
        <Img
          as={motion.img}
          src={this.props.selectedMedia.url}
          alt="Enlarged Pic"
          ref={this.mediaRef}
          initial={{ y: "-100vh" }}
          animate={{ y: "0" }}
        />
      );
    } else if (this.props.selectedMedia.type.includes("video")) {
      //<ModalVideo channel = "custom" url = { this.props.selectedMedia.url } />
      return (
        <Iframe2
          //width = "560"
          //height = "560"
          allow="fullscreen *; autoplay; encrypted-media"
          allowfullscreen="true"
          title="video"
          src={this.props.selectedMedia.url}
          ref={this.mediaRef}
        />
      );
    }
  };

  handleClick = e => {
    if (this.mediaRef && !this.mediaRef.current.contains(e.target))
      this.props.setSelectedMedia(null);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ModalContainer
        as={motion.div}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      >
        {this.renderMedia()}
      </ModalContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default Modal;
```

Thank you very much for your help.